# C# h323 calls with gatekeeper

Tags: c#, .net, voip, h.323

I am looking for a simple voip lib (.net or .net frendly) to make calls using h323 with gatekeeper (I have hardware gatekeeper). My app must call a phone number and play an audio file when the user answers. I found a few libs but they are too big and costly.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17048/Examples-to-create-your-Conferencing-System-in-NET

Answer (score 1):

There are only very H.323 libraries available and to my knowledge none of them supports C# directly.

The only 2 OpenSource libaries for H.323 are [H323Plus](http://www.h323plus.org/) and [OPAL](http://www.opalvoip.org/). Both are C++. OPAL also has a limited C API, but in my view H323Plus is the better H.323 library.

Commercially there is H.323 stack from Radvision, but as far as I know it also only supports C / C++.

All of these libraries can easily register and make calls with a gatekeeper.